# PEAR included with MAMP: how to access via Terminal?

Tags: terminal, pear, mamp

I'm trying to run a command that downloads a bit of software using PEAR installed with MAMP.

Here's the command I run in Terminal:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
```

The Terminal responds with:

*-bash: pear: command not found*

Could someone please advise how to access PEAR that comes pre-installed with MAMP?

Path to MAMP on my Mac is /Applications/MAMP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use mamp but i think you can find the pear here:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pear
```

you can simply add some alias to make it shorter, something like

```
alias mamppear="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pear"
```